# Deploy a new Sitecore environment to Azure App Service

Tags: azure

Following steps in this [link](https://doc.sitecore.net/cloud/working_with_sitecore_azure/configuring_sitecore_azure/deploy_a_new_sitecore_environment_to_azure_app_service):

I uploaded the standard Sitecore 8.2 rev. 161115 (WDP XP0 package).zip to a newly created azure storage file share and used the link with the SAS token in it in the parameters json (link below altered to prevent package being available to the public).

https://XXXXXXXstorage.file.core.windows.net/wdp/Sitecore%208.2%20rev.%20161115%20(WDP%20XP0%20package).zip?st=2016-12-13T13%3A48%3A00Z&se=2020-12-14T13%3A48%3A00Z&sp=rl&sv=2015-12-11&sr=f&sig=y48hyhmQc9B2alOAve%2BfFLEdO9ETXyMfwmR%2FNDj8XSE%3D

I get the error message below.

This is a newly created azure trial with the $200 credit. I would appreciate it if someone can let me know if anything in the log jumps out at them.

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 8:16:20 AM - Resource Microsoft.Web/sites/extensions 'xp0-dev-single/MSDeploy' failed with message '{
  "status": "failed",
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
    "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'failed'.",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "Failed",
        "message": "AppGallery Deploy Failed: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: Blob type of the blob reference doesn't match blob type of the blob. ---&amp;gt; 
System.InvalidOperationException: Blob type of the blob reference doesn't match blob type of the blob.\r\n   at 
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob.UpdateAfterFetchAttributes(BlobAttributes blobAttributes, HttpWebResponse response, Boolean ignoreMD5)\r\n   at 
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob.&amp;lt;&amp;gt;c__DisplayClass18.&amp;lt;FetchAttributesImpl&amp;gt;b__17(RESTCommand`1 cmd, HttpWebResponse resp, Exception ex, 
OperationContext ctx)\r\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext)\r\n   --- End 
of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext 
operationContext)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.AppGalleryPackage.IsPremiumApp()\r\n   at 
Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.DeploymentController.CheckCanDeployIfAppIsPremium(AppGalleryPackageInfo packageInfo, Boolean&amp;amp; isPremium)\r\nRequest 
Information\r\nRequestID:a1fdaf21-001a-0135-0c4b-559fec000000\r\nRequestDate:Tue, 13 Dec 2016 14:15:56 GMT\r\nStatusMessage:OK\r\n'\r\nFailed to download package.\r\nAppGallery Deploy 
Failed: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: Blob type of the blob reference doesn't match blob type of the blob. ---&gt; System.InvalidOperationException: Blob type of the blob 
reference doesn't match blob type of the blob.\r\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob.UpdateAfterFetchAttributes(BlobAttributes blobAttributes, HttpWebResponse response, 
Boolean ignoreMD5)\r\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass14.&lt;GetBlobImpl&gt;b__11(RESTCommand`1 cmd, HttpWebResponse resp, Exception ex, 
OperationContext ctx)\r\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndGetResponse[T](IAsyncResult getResponseResult)\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndExecuteAsync[T](IAsyncResult result)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 
endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at 
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at 
Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.AppGalleryPackage.&lt;Download&gt;d__a.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at 
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at 
Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.AppGalleryPackage.&lt;Download&gt;d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at 
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at 
Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.DeploymentController.&lt;DownloadAndDeployPackage&gt;d__d.MoveNext()\r\nRequest 
Information\r\nRequestID:a1fdaf25-001a-0135-0d4b-559fec000000\r\nRequestDate:Tue, 13 Dec 2016 14:15:57 GMT\r\nStatusMessage:OK\r\n'"
      }
    ]
  }
}'
At C:\Projects\GitHub\Sitecore.Azure\Cloud.Services.Provisioning.SDK\tools\Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.psm1:78 char:31
+ ... eployment = New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name $Name -ResourceG ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet

New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 8:16:20 AM - AppGallery Deploy Failed: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: Blob type of the blob reference doesn't match blob type of the 
blob. ---&amp;gt; System.InvalidOperationException: Blob type of the blob reference doesn't match blob type of the blob.
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob.UpdateAfterFetchAttributes(BlobAttributes blobAttributes, HttpWebResponse response, Boolean ignoreMD5)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob.&amp;lt;&amp;gt;c__DisplayClass18.&amp;lt;FetchAttributesImpl&amp;gt;b__17(RESTCommand`1 cmd, HttpWebResponse resp, Exception ex, 
OperationContext ctx)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.AppGalleryPackage.IsPremiumApp()
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.DeploymentController.CheckCanDeployIfAppIsPremium(AppGalleryPackageInfo packageInfo, Boolean&amp;amp; isPremium)
Request Information
RequestID:a1fdaf21-001a-0135-0c4b-559fec000000
RequestDate:Tue, 13 Dec 2016 14:15:56 GMT
StatusMessage:OK
'
Failed to download package.
AppGallery Deploy Failed: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: Blob type of the blob reference doesn't match blob type of the blob. ---&gt; System.InvalidOperationException: 
Blob type of the blob reference doesn't match blob type of the blob.
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob.UpdateAfterFetchAttributes(BlobAttributes blobAttributes, HttpWebResponse response, Boolean ignoreMD5)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass14.&lt;GetBlobImpl&gt;b__11(RESTCommand`1 cmd, HttpWebResponse resp, Exception ex, OperationContext ctx)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndGetResponse[T](IAsyncResult getResponseResult)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndExecuteAsync[T](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.AppGalleryPackage.&lt;Download&gt;d__a.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.AppGalleryPackage.&lt;Download&gt;d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.DeploymentController.&lt;DownloadAndDeployPackage&gt;d__d.MoveNext()
Request Information
RequestID:a1fdaf25-001a-0135-0d4b-559fec000000
RequestDate:Tue, 13 Dec 2016 14:15:57 GMT
StatusMessage:OK
'
At C:\Projects\GitHub\Sitecore.Azure\Cloud.Services.Provisioning.SDK\tools\Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.psm1:78 char:31
+ ... eployment = New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name $Name -ResourceG ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet

New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 8:16:20 AM - Template output evaluation skipped: at least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please 
see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.
At C:\Projects\GitHub\Sitecore.Azure\Cloud.Services.Provisioning.SDK\tools\Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.psm1:78 char:31
+ ... eployment = New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name $Name -ResourceG ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet

New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 8:16:20 AM - Template output evaluation skipped: at least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please 
see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.
At C:\Projects\GitHub\Sitecore.Azure\Cloud.Services.Provisioning.SDK\tools\Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.psm1:78 char:31
+ ... eployment = New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name $Name -ResourceG ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unlike the Sitecore XP1 and XM1 packages, the XP0 package contains a zip inside the zip.
You need to unpack that zip to your hard drive first (so it directly has the Content folder, and other files directly inside it), then upload it to your BlobStorage. Use the link of that blob in your ARM template parameters, and the install should work fine.

Comment: ahh, so silly - I didn't even think to look inside. I am re-doing now. Will mark as answer in a few minutes when everything works swimingly :)

Comment: Well now I get the error message below but I will mark this as closed since my original question is answered. Thanks Sean (if memory serves, I think we met in person in 2010 at DreamCore in Boston)

New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 9:36:59 AM - Resource Microsoft.Sql/servers 
'xp0-dev-sql' failed with message '{
  "code": "45157",
  "message": "Server 'xp0-dev-sql' is busy with another operation. Please try your 
operation later.",

Comment: I think 45157 is just a delay in me running the remove resource group and the group and resources actually being removed. So when I try to redo the powershell command with the same ID it is mad at trying to create another sql resource with the same name.

Comment: @Colema18 If you don't manage to solve the new error, feel free to post it as a new question.